# Calculate Average of value using two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

In project i have two tables

- Restaurant (RestaurantId, Name, Adress)
- RestaurantReview (ReviewId, RestaurantId, Mark)

One restaurant can have several opinions. I would like my application to display restaurant and the average of its ratings. I create code:

```
var resReviews = (
  from x in _context.Restaurant
  join y in _context.Reviews on x.IdRestauracji equals y.RestaurantId into z
  from a in z
  group a by a.RestaurantId into g
  select new
  {

     RatingAverage = g.Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Mark))
  }
).ToList();
```

In list are saved calculated average mark. I would also like to have restaurant information saved on the list. I try create something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var resReviews = (
  from x in _context.Restaurant
  join y in _context.Reviews on x.IdRestauracji equals y.RestaurantId into z
  from a in z
  group a by a.RestaurantId into g
  select new
  {
     Restaurant = g.FirstOrDefault();
     RatingAverage = g.Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Mark))
  }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need group when you have where?  You group creates a tow dimensional array <key, list<object>>.  You first level array will always have one item ID 12.  Your code would make sense if you removed the Where.  The from a in z is not needed either.  You need a lft outer join because not all restaurants have reviews and without the left out join you will only get restaurants that have reviews.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: I corrected the code in my question, I used "Where" only to test the code in my project in app. In my code, all restaurants have reviews

Comment: Look at link for Left Outer Join.  You do not need from a in z, instead you need the left outer join syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you first join two sequences into new intermediate sequence `z` of anonymous type `{ResturantId, Name, Address, ReviewId, Mark}`; then you filter `z` to get only records with appropriate RestaurantId, then group by restaurant id (useless, I suppose, as you get only one restaurant id in result set), so...

The problem is that `g.FirstOrDefault()` type is type of `z` sequence entry - anonymous type (like cross-product of Restaurant and Review); to get Restaurnt, you can either construct new instance, or fetch it from `_context.Restaurants` based on `RestaurantId` you have

Comment: Can I do it in this query or do I have to create a new object outside of it?

Comment: Yep, both options: `... select new { Restaurant = (from r in _context.Restaurants where r.RestaurantId == 12 select r) ...}` or `... { Restaurant = g.Select(gr => new Restaurant { Name = gr.Name, Adress = gr.Adress, Id = gr.Id}).FirstOrDefault() ...}`

Comment: In my code create  `select new{Restaurant = g.Select(gr => new Restaurant{ Name= gr.Restaurant.Name}).FirstOrDefault(), RatingAverage = g.Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.AvgMark))}` and i got error while program is compile -> System.InvalidOperationException: „Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable<Restaurant>(Select<Reviews, Restaurant>